# Python, .format(), and UTF-8

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

My background is in Perl, but I'm giving Python plus BeautifulSoup a try for a new project.

In this example, I'm trying to extract and present the link targets and link text contained in a single page.  Here's the source:

```
table_row = u'<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>'.encode('utf-8')
link_text = unicode(link.get_text()).encode('utf-8')
link_target = link['href'].encode('utf-8')
line_out = unicode(table_row.format(link_text, link_target))
```

All those explicit calls to .encode('utf-8') are my attempt to make this work, but they don't seem to help -- it's likely that I'm completely misunderstanding something about how Python 2.7 handles Unicode strings.

Anyway.  This works fine up until it encounters U+2013 in a URL (yes, really).  At that point it bombs out with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test2.py", line 30, in <module>
  line_out = unicode(table_row.encode('utf-8').format(link_text, link_target.encode('utf-8')))
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 79: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Presumably .format(), even applied to a Unicode string, is playing silly-buggers and trying to do a .decode() operation.  And as ASCII is the default, it's using that, and of course it can't map U+2013 to an ASCII character, and thus...

The options seem to be to remove it or convert it to something else, but really what I want is to simply preserve it.  Ultimately (this is just a little test case) I need to be able to present working clickable links.

The BS3 documentation suggests changing the default encoding from ASCII to UTF-8 but reading comments on similar questions that looks to be a really bad idea as it'll muck up dictionaries.

Short of using Python 3.2 instead (which means no Django, which we're considering for part of this project) is there some way to make this work cleanly?

Comment: as a basic rule of thumb, decode (to unicode) on input and encode (to desired encoding) on output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, note that your two code samples disagree on the text of the problematic line:

```
line_out = unicode(table_row.encode('utf-8').format(link_text, link_target.encode('utf-8')))
```

vs

```
line_out = unicode(table_row.format(link_text, link_target))
```

The first is the one from the traceback, so it's the one to look at.  Assuming the rest of your first code sample is accurate, `table_row` is a byte-string, because you took a unicode string and encoded it.  Byte strings can't be encoded, so Python 2 implicitly converts table_row from byte-string to unicode by decoding it as ascii.  Hence the error message, "UnicodeDecodeError from ascii".

You need to decide what strings will be byte strings and which will be unicode strings, and be disciplined about it.  I recommend keeping all text as Unicode strings as much as possible.

Here's a presentation I gave at PyCon that explains it all: [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain?](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Comment: Aha.  Okay, thanks.  It looks like an earlier attempt at understanding this led to my sticking .encode() everywhere, not realising that this would convert from a Unicode string to a byte string.

Removing all those seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: Also, mea culpa on the inconsistent code snippets.  I culled the relevant lines from the code as-it-was, and the error from a previous run which had been having the same problem.

Comment: This presentation is so good! Thanks for sharing (and for giving it!).